# "Neither a minute" usage?

Tags: word-choice

Which of the following sentences is more idiomatic or is there any other way to say it?

> 1. In case neither a minute has gone since you left.
> 2. In case a minute hasn't gone since you left.

Comment: Or do you mean *nary a minute*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, hopeful suggestions include:

"In case you'll be out for less than a minute, [you will still need to turn on your voicemail]."

"If it is the case that it's less than one minute before you return, [payroll won't count it against you]."

"If you return in less than a minute, [you won't need to clock out]."

"Just in case it hasn't been a full minute since you left, [etc]."

Answer (score 3):

Neither of those is something a native speaker would generate, and both would be perceived to be ungrammatical.

- In case a minute hasn’t passed since you left, the door won’t have locked behind you yet because it has a sixty-second timer.
- A minute hasn’t passed yet since you left.
- Not even a minute has passed since you left.

Comment: A native speaker of French might *generate* something similar.

Comment: I'm having a *lot* of trouble finding that first one "valid". I can see what you're getting at, but it seems to me the following clause needs to be something more like *a precautionary action taken in order to deal with the case actually arising*. Yours looks more like the *in case* should be *in the case that*, which is pretty ugly phrasing at the best of times. OTOH, *"In case a minute hasn't passed, I'll wait another few seconds before I press the button to remotely detonate the bomb I put in your handbag, because I want to make sure you're well away from my house before it blows"*.

Comment: @Noah Probably not, says a Frenchman.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, it’s more like “In the event that. . . .”   And yeah, it’s awkward. I was trying to get it to something closer to what the Opie was aiming for, but it is a long and tortuous journey.

Comment: @tchrist: I'm sure my example isn't the best that can be done, but it's steering closer to the *In case X happens, I'll do Y* idiomatic usage we're looking for here - as a *precautionary measure against a negative future outcome* or future discovery of something that's maybe already gone tits up. Of course, we've no idea whether OP's got *any* of these meanings in mind. But you and I have, so at least *we're* communicating! :)

Comment: @Noah vous voulez dire ?  Qu'est-ce qu'on entend, un espèce de "au cas où ?"

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard either used. I'm not sure what it is your trying to say but perhaps the following might be useful.

> In case no time has past since you left.

or

> No time at all has past since you left.

Comment: AmE uses "passed" as the past participle of "to pass." Is "past" passing on the other side of the pond? @Rodgers

Comment: @livresque I don't dare say if it's wrong or not, but _passed_ is much more common!

Comment: @livresque no, en-GB has *passed* as both the simple past and past participle of *pass*, with *past* as the adjective, noun and preposition that's related. Both are pronounced the same in most accents, and *past* comes from an old variant spelling of *passed*, but they've been separate since the Middle English period.

Comment: @JonHanna, GTA for validating my resources.

Answer (score 1):

> If you return within a minute...